# Dropdown menu loads before clicking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dropdown menu, where you have to click before the dropdown menu shows up. But everytime I load the page, the dropdown menu also loads.  I have really tried to look through my code, and I have a feeling it is in the start of the code.

Can anybody see what is wrong in this code?

```
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="0" data-hover=
                      "dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Feature <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                      </a>
                        <!--container start-->
                        <div class="login-bg">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="form-wrapper">
                                <form class="form-signin wow fadeInUp" action="index.html">
                                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">sign in now</h2>
                                <div class="login-wrap">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                                        <span class="pull-right">
                                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"> Forgot Password?</a>

                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                                    <p>or you can sign in via social network</p>
                                    <div class="login-social-link">
                                        <a href="index.html" class="facebook">
                                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                            Facebook
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="index.html" class="twitter">
                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                            Twitter
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="registration">
                                        Don't have an account yet?
                                        <a class="" href="registration.html">
                                            Create an account
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                  <!-- Modal -->
                                  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                                          <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="modal-header">
                                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                  <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-body">
                                                  <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.</p>
                                                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">

                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                                  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Submit</button>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <!-- modal -->

                              </form>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--container end-->
                  </li>
                  <!-- /li dropdown for login -->
              </ul>
              <!-- /ul for navigationbar -->
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--header end-->
```

Comment: css code would be nice to have, or we weren't able to help you with those dropdowns...

Comment: Hello Synoon. I accidently posted some more dropdowns that I was supposed to, but I have edited my question now. The css is just standard bootstrap, and I did not make any changes on the css/js files. But I think it is the dropdown-toggle there is going wrong.

Comment: Please, fix your code, or better, create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we could run it and see the problem. Also, Where is the `dropdown`? Is that the `Feature` link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is standard code from bootstrap you can use it for your dropdown.

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Feature <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
        <!-- your dropdown container start-->
        <div class="login-bg dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <div class="container">
                 <!-- your html code can be here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it help you to solve your problem.

If you still have query please post your proper html or create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) / [bootply snippet here](http://www.bootply.com/new#)

Comment: Thank you a lot Nimmi. That solved my problem. I thought it was the start of the bootstrap, thanks a lot.